# python trading bot create DCA safety order

Tags: python, bots

I am working on creating a trading bot with Python. The strategy I got working in the bot and it can start a deal, but what I am looking for is the code to activate safety orders like 3commas has.
Using the following settings I need a script to calculate the order price and amount to open a safety order:

- Max safety trades count
- Max active safety trades count
- Price deviation to open safety orders (% from initial order)
- Safety order volume scale
- Safety order step scale

This is what I have so far:

```py
initial_price=40000
safety_order_size=100
price_deviation = 1.5
max_safety_orders_count=10
max_active_safety_orders_count=1
safety_order_volume_scale=1.19
safety_order_step_scale=0.95

safety_order_prices = []
price_deviation_list = []
current_price = initial_price

for i in range(max_safety_orders_count):
    safety_order_price = initial_price * (1 - price_deviation / 100)
    safety_order_prices.append(safety_order_price)
    price_deviation_list.append(price_deviation)
    print(price_deviation_list)
    
    price_deviation = (price_deviation * safety_order_step_scale)
    print(price_deviation)
```

I have looked on the internet and asked chatgpt for the source code or the formula to calculate, but found nothing.
Does anybody hear know how to do this?

Comment: is your question about the algorithms and definitions needed to create these "DCA safety orders" or is your question about a problem you encountered while trying to program it? As it stands, this question is not focused enough